# How do I launch powershell task with some script

Tags: conemu

I'm a little confused how do I configure a new task in ConEmu to run launch powershell console with -File parameter. if I add -file "filename.ps1" then that file is executed and then console is closed, I'd like to console to rename open.

Comment: Learn about `PowerShell -?` and `-noexit` switch.

Comment: Why it's not required -noexit switch on default Powershell task? Just added -noexit and it still exits

Comment: Not a `-file` but `-command`.